How to find out the resolution of my webcam?
Is there a way to find out the pixels of the camera that's in my MBP?
I went into system information, and all I got is..
FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in):

  Model ID: UVC Camera VendorID_1452 ProductID_34068
  Unique ID:    0x8020000005ac8514

Is there a setting in my system that I can open and see what my webcam resolution is?

What does finder and the OS say  if you use QuickTime to record a short videoto your documents folder or desktop?

Are you trying to find out programmatically, or do you just want to know?  It says what the resolution is on the laptop's spec sheet.

@bmike That's not what I want to do. Because that means QuickTime used that resolution, not what my webcam is capable of. Another decision in the middle.

@MarcWilson Where is the spec sheet in the mac?

@SaadRehmanShah It's on the Apple web site.
